# Error with api.list_members: TweepError: [{'code': 34, 'message': 'Sorry, that page does not exist.'}]

Tags: python, tweepy

```
import tweepy

consumer_key = "***"
consumer_secret = "***"
access_token_key = "***"
access_token_secret = "***"

auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_token_key, access_token_secret)
api = tweepy.API(auth)

screen_name = 'hogehoge'
list_slug = "list01"
members = api.list_members(list_slug, screen_name)
members
```

Then, I got this message.

```
TweepError: [{'code': 34, 'message': 'Sorry, that page does not exist.'}]
```

The list surely exists.
How should I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

If that list does exist, it is private:

[image: @hogehoge lists]

https://twitter.com/hogehoge/lists